# Using a subplot to plot a function several times

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a fonction that create a rugby field :

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.patches import Arc
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

def draw_pitch_horizontal():
    # focus on only half of the pitch
    #Pitch Outline & Centre Line
    fig=plt.figure() #set up the figures
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    
    Pitch = Rectangle([0,0], width = 120, height = 70, fill = False)
    essai1 = Rectangle([0,0], width = 10, height = 70, fill = False, color='gray',hatch='/')
    essai2 = Rectangle([110,0], width = 1070, height = 70, fill = False, color='gray',hatch='/')
    en_but1 = ConnectionPatch([10,0], [10,80], "data", "data")
    en_but2 = ConnectionPatch([110,0], [110,70], "data", "data")
    cinq_metres1 = ConnectionPatch([15,0], [15,70], "data", "data",ls='--',color='gray')
    cinq_metres2 = ConnectionPatch([105,0], [105,70], "data", "data",ls='--',color='gray')
    midline = ConnectionPatch([60,0], [60,70], "data", "data")
    vingtdeux_metres1 = ConnectionPatch([32,0], [32,70], "data", "data")
    vingtdeux_metres2 = ConnectionPatch([88,0], [88,70], "data", "data")
    dix_metres1 = ConnectionPatch([50,0], [50,70], "data", "data",ls='--',color='gray')
    dix_metres2 = ConnectionPatch([70,0], [70,70], "data", "data",ls='--',color='gray')
    centreCircle = plt.Circle((60,35),0.5,color="black", fill = True)
    poteau1a = plt.Circle((10,32.2),0.5,color="black", fill = True)
    poteau1b = plt.Circle((10,37.8),0.5,color="black", fill = True)
    poteau2a = plt.Circle((110,32.2),0.5,color="black", fill = True)
    poteau2b = plt.Circle((110,37.8),0.5,color="black", fill = True)
    

    element = [essai1, essai2, Pitch, en_but1, en_but2, cinq_metres1, cinq_metres2, midline, vingtdeux_metres1, 
    vingtdeux_metres2,centreCircle,poteau1a,poteau1b,poteau2a,poteau2b,dix_metres1,dix_metres2]
    for i in element:
        ax.add_patch(i)
    
    return fig,ax
```

I created a function with a team in argument and the function plots the average start and end of a sequence on a pitch thanks to the previous function.

```
def plot_sequence_moyenne(TEAM):
    
    df_team = df_summary[((df_summary.hometeam == TEAM)|(df_summary.awayteam == TEAM))].reset_index(drop=True)
    df_timeline = pd.concat([prg.Match(df_team['url'][i]).timeline for i in range(len(df_team))],axis=0)
    df_timeline_team = df_timeline[df_timeline.team_name == TEAM].reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df_timeline_team.x_coord.mean())
    print(df_timeline_team.x_coord_end.mean())
    
    (fig,ax) = draw_pitch_horizontal() #overlay our different objects on the pitch
    plt.ylim(-2, 72)
    plt.xlim(-0.2, 120.4)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_facecolor('#c2dff4')
    plt.axis('off')

    zone_sequence = Rectangle([df_timeline_team.x_coord.mean(),0], width = (df_timeline_team.x_coord_end.mean()-df_timeline_team.x_coord.mean()), height = 70, fill = True, color='darkseagreen',alpha=0.7,edgecolor='black')
    ax.add_patch(zone_sequence)
    plt.title("TEAM 1" + " - Séquences moyennes")
    plt.show()
```

This is what I obtain with this :

[image]

However, I would like to know how to create a huge subplot in order to have a graph with 10 subplots of pitch if I have ten teams for exemple.

Thanks in advance for your help and your time

Comment: I would use subplots to make the fig and axes, `fig, axs = plt.subplots(n_teams, 1)`, and then pass the axes to your functions `draw_pitch_horizontal` and `plot_sequence_moyenne` for each team.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ! Could you just show me who to use the axes created in my functions ? 


I tried doing that  : fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
for ax in axs:
    draw_pitch_horizontal_test(ax)
    plot_sequence_moyenne_test("TEAM",ax)
 
by adding variable to the definition of my functions but this doesn't work => the subplots are empty

Comment: Did you remove the figure/axis creation lines in `draw_pitch_horizontal`?  Make sure you are plotting to the axis you pass as an argument and not some other thing.  I've made that mistake before.  Also, you should switch to `ax.Circle` (or whatever the analog is) instead of `plt.Circle`.